# resize file after certain condition. c++ resize_file not work in loop

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

i don't know whats the problem with filesystem resize_file standart c++ 17 in visual studio. when i test the STL with manual. it can resize as expect. when using in conditional. its like a bug. the result output is split 2 parts. i test it a file 2MB size. the result i should expected is **input file** should be resize to **0 byte** in the end.

```
 std::ifstream input("D:/input.exe", std::ios::binary);
    if (input.is_open())
    {
        std::ofstream output("D:/output.exe", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate | std::ios::app);
        auto p = std::filesystem::path("D:/input.exe");
        std::vector<char> buffer(1048576);
        do
        {
            long long setPosition;

            if (std::filesystem::file_size(p) > buffer.size())
            {
                setPosition = (std::filesystem::file_size(p) - buffer.size());
                input.seekg(setPosition);
            }
            else
            {
                input.seekg(0);
            }

            input.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
            std::streamsize dataSize = input.gcount();
            if (dataSize)
            {
                output.seekp(0);
                output.write(buffer.data(), dataSize);
                long long resizeFile = (std::filesystem::file_size(p) - dataSize);
                std::filesystem::resize_file(p, resizeFile);
            }
            else
            {
                output.close();
                input.close();
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File is not exist";
    }
```

Comment: If you want to truncate the input file, why don't you do it once, ***after*** you have read all the data?

Comment: I also suggest you skip the `gcount` check to see when you read all the file, and instead do e.g. `while (input.read(...)) { ... }`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it just example for small file. if the file is big like says 8GB it will problem to read all and truncate.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i need the gcount for my api. and don't have problem with my api input / ouput. but the thing problem is **resize_file STL**.

Comment: I don't see a problem since you read it in chunks. You won't be reading *all* of it into memory.

Comment: And don't forget that truncating the file will truncate at the *end*, the data you have already read from the file will still be in the file, while you remove data at the end that you will never have a chance to read (if it even works considering that the file is already open for reading).

Comment: What "API"? The code you show could be implemented basically like `while (input.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size()) { output.write(buffer.data(), input.gcount()); } input.close(); std::filesystem::resize_file(p, 0);`

Comment: Some Encryption api.  i need realltime resize file as the data in the chunk already process and output. if not. it will need twice space to do that things. like if i need to process 4GB file i need other avaiable space for temporary.

Comment: Perhaps you should delete this question, and write a new one describing the *actual* problem you need to solve (and how you tried to solve it)? This question in its current form is very much an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: in here we talking resize_file api. not full project code for you to use. u still don't know the meaning resize_file? or are u script kiddie that steal other full code for personal use? its clear the problem here. if your mind is not clear. ti don't mind u take a sleep and come back. when, your mind is clear.

Comment: @stephen.hawk be nice. I'm pretty sure Some programmer dude knows exactly what `resize_file` does. Dude is asking you do check out the guide how to ask good questions - and that includes providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - not the full project code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do will not work. `resize_file` will truncate the file at the end of the file, so when you read X bytes from the start of the file and then truncate the file, you will chop off X bytes at the end of the file. You will probably end up with both `input.exe` and `output.exe` containing the beginning of the original `input.exe`. What you should do is to truncate the file after you've read it. The below will make `output.exe` a copy of the original `input.exe` and `input.exe` will be 0 bytes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    auto p = std::filesystem::path("D:/input.exe");
    std::ifstream input(p, std::ios::binary);
    if (input)
    {
        std::ofstream output("D:/output.exe", std::ios::binary);
        std::vector<char> buffer(1048576);
        while (true) {
            input.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
            std::streamsize dataSize = input.gcount();
            if (dataSize==0) break;
            output.write(buffer.data(), dataSize);
        }
        std::filesystem::resize_file(p, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File does not exist";
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not realtime. resize file. i just edit my question to add seekg if u said truncate will start from end. i seekg from specific position and loop.

Comment: That will not matter. `resize_file` will either shrink or extend the file at the end.
You can't remove the beginning of a regular file in realtime. What you describe sounds like a `FIFO` / named pipe.

Comment: I dont know what u means First In First out. if u know realtime resize file. after doing processing with the read data. if not realtime. it need twice space for temporary to doing processing.

Comment: A named pipe is a FIFO which is a filesystem entity that one process can write to and another one can read from it. Its size is the number of bytes in the pipe, so when you write to or read from it, it'll resize itself. When working with regular files, then, yes, at one point it will require the double size, even if you start reading from the end of the input file. When you write the first chunk to the output file, that must also be positioned at the end of that file so there you get the double size directly (if the want the output data in the same order as the input was).

Comment: I edited my question, and now the input as expected. but the output different output.

Comment: If I understand what you've done now correctly, you read backwards from the end of the input file and write to output from the beginning of the file, so the output file will have all the chunks in reverse order. Do you need the data in output in the same order as you have it in input? Since you're reading an `.exe` file, I guess you do, and in that case, you might as well just read from the start of the input file since you will never get around the temporary doubling of the size for a regular file.

Comment: if the problem is only reverse output. i add again seekp output to always to beginning. but, the result different? whats the problem agian?

Comment: Do you need the data in the output file to be in the same order as in the input file?

Comment: Yes, as u know. i'm using seekg to read from specific position and output pointer always from **0** (beginning). but, i test it. it output half size from original 2MB.

Comment: Then, if you read backwards from the end of the input file, you need to write backwards from the end of the output file - which should be resized to the same size as the input file when you start. As you see, you do not get around the problem.

Comment: i think the problem is with output. i write from scratch my code to using do while for clear code. it still output wrong byte.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by _problem_? If you read from the end of one file and write to the beginning of another, the chunks of data in the second file will be reversed compared to the original file.
Your original question should be answered by now. What you are trying to do can't be done for regular files (on _normal_ filesystems). Do you agree or do you think there's a way around that?

Comment: in my code with seekp. it should point pointer output always start from 0. so with a logic read backwards. if it keep output from 0 pointer. and the result should be original file. if my logic not wrong.

Comment: The `output.seekp(0)` seems pointless on a file opened with `std::ios::app`.
Take a pen and paper and draw the chunks of data in `input`. Try to create a copy in `output` without requiring the double amount of space. 
Another thing: Since you're not `trunc`ating the output file when opening it, doesn't it get bigger and bigger for every time you run your program?

Comment: yeah, thats the wrong as i read, it will always concatening from end file.. it should not. std::ios::app, but as i search i try with std::ios::ate and std::ios::binary. but its not concatenating. like std::ios::app.

Comment: Yes, it's one of the problems. Have you figured out how to do this operation with pen and paper? If it's impossible to solve on paper, it'll be twice as hard to implement.

Comment: I know, how to solve it now. i write it to scratch again.

Comment: Please describe how if you've managed to do it without shuffling down all data in `input` while you read it. I'm very curious.